# Jest environment has been torn down error in graphql, nodejs project. Used jest.useFakeTimers but still getting the error

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, apollo-server, ts-jest

Getting ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down From office/test/office.test.ts.
Used jest.useFakeTimers(); after imports, but the issue still exists. Is there any way to resolve it ?

Here is my jest.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from "@jest/types"
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
    },
    testRegex: '(/__test__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$',
    moduleFileExtensions: [ 'js','ts'],
    testEnvironment: "jest-environment-node",
    fakeTimers: {
        enableGlobally: true,
      },
    verbose: true
}
export default config
```

The test file office.test.ts

```
import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server'
import {expect,test,jest} from '@jest/globals';
import officeGql  from '../controllers/controller'
jest.useFakeTimers();
test('Office Module Test', async () => {
  let typeDefs = officeGql.types
  let resolvers = officeGql.resolvers
  let testServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });
   const response = await testServer.executeOperation({
     query: `query offices(limit: $limit,offset: $offset){name, address}`,
       variables: { limit: 10,offset:0 },
   });
   expect(response.data).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a **openhandle**. To fix this all you have to do is

```
try {
let typeDefs = officeGql.types
  let resolvers = officeGql.resolvers
  let testServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });
   const response = await testServer.executeOperation({
     query: `query offices(limit: $limit,offset: $offset){name, address}`,
       variables: { limit: 10,offset:0 },
   });
   expect(response.data).toBeTruthy();
} catch (err) {
} finally {
  await testServer.close()
}
```

this is a temp fix and will work when I find a better way I will post it